# Keep and restore WebView content

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have a website (application) that contains a lot of javascript (Note: I can send js commands into the site for opening any views). This site opens for a very long time (20-30 sec for parsing, reading configurations etc).

My application has many WebViews in different parts of the application. For example - I have the listview with 100+ items, by clicking on the item should be opened new fragment with WebView (with web application).

i.e. I do not want to re-open the site every time I create a WebView, it takes a very long time, I want to open the site once (!) and work with it through JS API.

I think that solution should be like this: 
1. when application started I should open the site in the hidden web-view
2. store webview content for the next usages
3. open new fragments with new webviews and insert stored at step2 content
4. send JS command into the opened site

But one question: What best way to store full webview content for re-usage?

I tried:

At first – the site should be opened from the cache

```
web_view.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
web_view.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
web_view.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
```

and keep the content as singleton (for example) per application

```
val bundle = Bundle()
web_view.saveState(bundle)
mySingleton.myStateHolder = bundle
```

and restore it if needed

```
web_view.restoreState(bundle)

//send js command
```

Great. But I Expect that:
1. webview state is cached with full content for the current state, including js and images
2. webview must be saved and restored without any errors (for example, site not fully loaded)
3. this solution must be reliable (!).

I'm not sure about all three points

In any case I can try to use one webview per application, but I think that it is very bad solution. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

What the best way for this case?

Comment: I don't mean to be negative, but I don't think you can do this reliably with webview - i.e. serialize/deserialize the full state including images etc. But you can use a single webview which you can "cache" across fragments as is - without serialization as long as there is a way to revert the JS commands and get the webview to original state. You can just create it in the background and then move it accross fragments as needed.

Comment: @daemontus Yes, I already thought about this solution. But  there is still the preservation of the state of the fragment and activity...

Comment: You'll have to use something custom for that anyway :/ Standard saveInstanceState method using Bundle objects will not handle more than ~1MB of data (I'm assuming you have way more than that since parsing is 20s) - which is also a reason webviews typically cannot be restored fully using standard mechanisms. But you can load local files into the webview - so you could at least save some javascript/images locally and avoid loading them from server every time.

Comment: I can save state of webview, for example, into application instance and restore it later. But I'm not sure about the reliability of this decision. Ill investigate more